# Why is there 丼 {どんぶり} in 丼勘定 {どんぶりかんじょう}?

Tags: etymology, set-phrases

How does 丼勘定 {どんぶりかんじょう} (sloppy accounting) related to 丼 {どんぶり} (bowl of rice with toppings)? I mean, why どんぶり of all foods and things? Was there special history for the origin of this set phrase?

Comment: @Karl True, but I believe that English idiom must have a history. For example "kick the bucket": http://www.infoplease.com/dictionary/brewers/kick-bucket.html  (which interestingly has nothing to do with what modern English refers as "bucket") .. so here I'm asking for the history why donburi is selected. I imagined must have something to do with feudal age joke or something.

Comment: It's the first time I hear this expression, but I'd say it quite makes sense intuitively... 丼 does give me the image of ingredients somewhat haphazardly thrown in together... The same way "stew" or "brew" might be used to describe something similar in English...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Judging by the following link, どんぶり in this phrase didn't originally refer to the bowl, but a pocket in the front of an apron, where money was kept:
http://gogen-allguide.com/to/donburikanjyou.html

If someone was throwing all the incoming money into one pocket and fishing out change for customers from same, they probably didn't have a great idea at any one time of how much they had or any way of keeping track.

http://www.samue.co.jp/shop/haori/ooedo4/ooedo4.html - this has an Edo-style "どんぶり" for a little visual reference (you'll note they use どんぶり勘定 with the hiragana).

Comment: That totally makes sense! Now this is another example where the actual origin of a phrase is nothing like what anyone would guess from the literal meaning (similar to "kick the bucket" case where it did not come from somebody standing on a bucket and kicking it to hang himself)

Answer (score 1):

First, let's be a bit more precise. saiga-jp.com [gives](http://www.saiga-jp.com/cgi-bin/dic.cgi?m=search&sc=0&f=0&j=%E4%B8%BC&g=&e=&s=&rt=0&start=1&sid=1314242595_34874)

丼 a china bowl

丼勘定 sloppy accounting, spending money unsystematically

i.e. the character refers to the bowl itself directly, and only by extension to food served in such a bowl.

Seems to me like it's a metaphor, and a fairly arbitrarily selected one. You might as well ask why English speakers "hit the nail on the head", as opposed to (doing anything else properly), when they get something right. 勘 has meanings like 'intuition' and 定 like 'determine', so (my guess!) the metaphor is of putting all the numbers (receipts?) into a bowl, swirling them around and pulling out a result that looks right.